# Folder update status with new file in Zabbix monitoring solution

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I've a Zabbix monitoring solution installed in my organisation to monitor critical alerts about various solutions. There is a new requirement to monitor a set of folders(located at different locations within same server) for any new file generated in X days(periodicity X is different for all folders). Does any script/template exists in zabbix to perform such alerting task.

Any help would be of great value!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use vfs.dir.count

Here is an example:
https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/380763-check-newest-file-in-folder